# Optimizing a functional using variational calculus

Tags: differential-equations, functional, variational-calculus

Here I am, trying to get the trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ that will minimize the following Lagrangian (i.e. the integrand of the functional) between $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,y_{eff})$ where $x_{eff}$ is defined as the point where $V(x_{eff},-1)=V(-1,-1)$.

So here's the integrand of the functional:

$L=\frac{1}{2}((\partial_tx)^2+(\partial_ty)^2)-V(x(t),y(t))$

with $V(x(t),y(t))$ defined as follows:

$(x(t)^2-1)^2(x(t)^2-\delta_1)+\frac{(y(t)^2-1)^2-\frac{\delta_2}{4}(y(t)-2)(y(t)+1)^2}{x(t)^2+\gamma}$

and

$x(-1)=-1=y(-1)$

$x(0)=x_{eff},y(0)=-1$

$x'(0)=y'(0)=0$

Yet I get the following error code:

```
NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function x appears with no arguments.
```

For the record, here's the code (for $\delta_1=\delta_2=\gamma=0.1$):

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
gamma = 0.1;
delta1 = 0.1;
delta2 = 0.1;
V[x[t_], y[t_]] := (x[t]^2 - 1)^2 (x[t]^2 - delta1) + ((y[t]^2 - 1)^2 - 
  delta2 (y[t] - 2) (y[t] + 1)^2/4)/(x[t]^2 + gamma);
U[x_, y_] := (x^2 - 1)^2 (x^2 - delta1) + ((y^2 - 1)^2 - 
  delta2 (y - 2) (y + 1)^2/4)/(x^2 + gamma);
ftn = 1/2 (D[x[t], t]^2 + D[y[t], t]^2) - V[x[t], y[t]];
Veff[x_] := U[x, -1];
x0 = FindRoot[Veff[x] == U[-1, -1], {x, -0.2}]
sln = EulerEquations[ftn, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
solution = NDSolve[{sln, x[-1] == -1, y[-1] == -1, x[0] == x0, y[0] == -1, x'[-1] == 0, y'[-1] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, -1, 0}]
```

It would be well-appreciated if I could have a plot as well.

Comment: your first error is that you use `x0 = FindRoot[Veff[x] == U[-1, -1], {x, -0.2}]`, because this results in `x0` being a rule like `x->...` but you only want the value.

Comment: The error message is to be taken literally. `x[0] == {x -> -0.316228}` is the problem (and is due to what halirutan says)

Comment: I've made some adjustments, but I am still stuck at a completely different step...

I get the following error code for that NDSolve implementation:

    `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.008829100660857013`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`